# Set text on Lagna chart

Tags: java, android, android-graphview

I required to implement a Astrology App where the user can check there Horoscope chart. I am calling Vedic Rishi API. I want to put the result on Lagna Chart where the data will come according to the user DOB, so please tell me exact what should I use GRAPHVIEW or anything else. I don't know anything about it so please share your experience with me thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may not be what exactly what you want but surely works for you if you give it a try..

Firstly add this image to your drawable and name it as lagnachart.[image]

Then add this code in your layout.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".others.LagnaChart">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:background="@drawable/lagnachart">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/topleftup"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:paddingLeft="30dp"
        android:text="1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/topleftup_txt"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/topleftup"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingLeft="30dp"
        android:text="This is top left up" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/topleftdown"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="30dp"
        android:text="1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/topleftdown_txt"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/topleftdown"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:text="This is top left down" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/toprightup"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:paddingRight="30dp"
        android:text="1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/toprightup_txt"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/toprightup"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingRight="30dp"
        android:text="This is top right up" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/toprightdown"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="30dp"
        android:text="1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/toprightdown_txt"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toprightdown"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:text="This is top right down" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bottomleftdown"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:paddingLeft="30dp"
        android:text="1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bottomleftdown_txt"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/bottomleftdown"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:text="This is bottom left down" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bottomleftup"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:paddingBottom="30dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:text="1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bottomleftup_txt"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/bottomleftup"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:text="This is bottom left up" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bottomrightdown"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:paddingRight="30dp"
        android:text="1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bottomrightdown_txt"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/bottomrightdown"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:text="This is bottom right down" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bottomrightup"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:paddingBottom="30dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:text="1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bottomrightup_txt"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottomrightup"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:text="This is bottom right up" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/centerleft"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:paddingLeft="30dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:text="1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/centerleft_txt"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/centerleft"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:text="This is center left" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/centerRight"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:paddingRight="30dp"
        android:text="1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/centerRight_txt"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/centerRight"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:text="This is center right" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/centerTop"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:text="1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/centerTop_txt"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/centerTop"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:text="This is center top" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/centerBottom"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:text="1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/centerBottom_txt"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/centerBottom"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:text="This is center bottom" />
</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Then initialize the textview in your Activity and set the data accordingly what you want. You will get an output something like this  :[image]

Comment: Thank you Sir for replying, can we take TextView as dynamically? And If I takes TextView in XML file then the text will move on their place I think.

Comment: You can take the textview dynamically. You will just need to adjust the textview position according to the view that you want.